# How to save Abstract object to Shared Preferences Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, abstract-class

I want to save abstract object to shared preferences.I get data with String from Shared preferences and when bind it to an Abstract class, I get some errors like that 
`"Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: Can't instantiate abstract class"`

How to get abstract object from shared preferences?

Thanks

Comment: you can't create an abstract object, that's why you can't save it. That's how Java works (same as most part of other languages). Extend from that abstract class, implement all abstract methods, and then you will be able to create instance.

Comment: Shared Preference is not a general storage for everything but you can extract your Object value and form a JSON or XAML string structure and store it instead. It's up to you on how you will do your Serialization/Deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot create an intance from an abstract class in java. You need to make something like this

```
public MyRealClass extends MyAbstractClass{

}
```

Your IDE should now tell you that you need to implement the needed methods from the abstract class.

You can now save the instance of **MyRealClass** to the **SharedPreferences** but only if you make it serializable or make the object to a **JSON** String. This can be done using libraries like **GSON**. 
It is not possible to save an object to the SharedPrefs directly.

**GSON** will take your instance and transforms it into a string. This string can be saved and later if you need the object again you can give the string to GSON and it will transform it back into the object. The used representation is called JSON, which is a standard format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

To save

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(myRealClassInstance);
prefsEditor.putString("myobj", json);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

for later loading

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("myobj", "");
MyRealClass obj = gson.fromJson(json, MyRealClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your Error: You can't create object of abstract class, you have to inherit abstract class to some class then only you can make an object to it.

Another one is, You can't store the object in shared preference. You can only store String, Integer, Boolean, Float, Long, and StringSet.

More info here.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html